# Jekyll on github doesn't works the same as local jekyll server

Tags: github, jekyll

[Project](https://github.com/lenville/lenville.github.io)
[demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20181127085837/https://lenville.com/)

[image: next button]
The next button works very well when I ran all the codes on local jekyll server.
But it doesn't work on online Github Jekyll server.

Looking forward to the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you
[using correct Jekyll](http://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages)

Currently

```
gem 'jekyll',     '=0.12.0'
```

Comment: Actually it is the version problem