# Jekyll remote theme doesn't work locally

Tags: ruby, windows, github, jekyll, github-pages

## Abstract

- I wanted to see a page in the local machine made by Jekyll using `gem "jekyll-remote-theme"`
- So I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`
- But a blank page came out

## What I want to achieve

- To see a page in the local machine made by Jekyll using `gem "jekyll-remote-theme"`.

I'm trying to build a blog in GitHub Pages with Jekyll and Minimal Mistakes. Before I push changes, I'd like to check if everything's fine with the pages.

## Environment

- Windows 8.1 64bit
- ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x64-mingw32]
- Jekyll 3.6.2

## What I did

1. `bundle exec jekyll new . --force`
2. Installed the theme with [GitHub Pages Method](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/quick-start-guide/#github-pages-method)
3. `bundle exec jekyll serve`

## What actually happened

I had an error related to `libcurl.dll`. Here is the message on Powershell.

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-remote-theme or o
>   ne of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured
>   , you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Could n
>   ot open library 'libcurl': (illegal characters) . Could not open libr
>   ary 'libcurl.dll': (illegal characters) . Could not open library 'lib
>   curl.so.4': (illegal characters) . Could not open library 'libcurl.so
>   .4.dll': (illegal characters) ' If you run into trouble, you can find
>    helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

I followed instructions in [GitHub Pages Dependencies Missing · Issue #17 · benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/issues/17#issuecomment-354677407) and the problem was solved.

Then another error came up with `bundle exec jekyll serve`. The page locally created is blank. http://127.0.0.1:4000/ shows nothing.

```
PS E:\workspace\mysite\dixhom.github.io> bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io
       Destination: E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
      Remote Theme: Using theme mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
     Build Warning: Layout 'single' requested in _posts/2018-02-06-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in 404.html does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page' requested in about.md.bak does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'home' requested in index.html does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'home' requested in index.md.bak does not exist.
                    done in 5.423 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

It looked like `jekyll` couldn't read layout files. In addition, the `_layouts` directory wasn't in the directory where I did `bundle exec jekyll new`. But by default, [what's in the `_layouts` directory is packaged in a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891463/jekyll-default-installation-doesnt-have-layouts-directory/38891696) so it's normal not to see the directory. So I just copied `_layouts` from [minimal-mistakes GitHub repo](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) to the local directory as a workaround.

Then, another error was raised.

```
PS E:\workspace\mysite\dixhom.github.io> bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io
       Destination: E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
      Remote Theme: Using theme mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
  Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'sidebar.html' in any of ["E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.io/_
includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site sourc
e. in /_layouts/single.html
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  Could not locate the included file 'sidebar.html' in any of ["E:/workspace/mysite/dixhom.github.i
o/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site so
urce.
```

I could have just copied `_includes` the same way but I believe the core of the problem lies in **`jekyll` failing to read necessary files from, for example, a GitHub repo**.

The weird thing is when I push local changes to GitHub, GitHub Pages shows 
a properly rendered page as shown below.

[image]

By the way, the repo is https://github.com/Dixhom/dixhom.github.io/tree/7132905f5515345eb78cd71bdad168a15f906a1c

I suspected `jekyll-remote-theme` doesn't work on the local environment so I googled "jekyll remote theme serve" which wasn't helpful.

Googling keywords like "remote theme Build Warning: Layout  does not exist." didn't help much.

- [jekyll - Github Pages renders blank page - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945114/github-pages-renders-blank-page)
  Different. Working on the local machine not on the github pages
- [Jekyll on github doesn't works the same as local jekyll server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500043/jekyll-on-github-doesnt-works-the-same-as-local-jekyll-server)
  Same.
- [Jekyll works locally but comes up blank on github pages - Help - Jekyll Talk](http://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-works-locally-but-comes-up-blank-on-github-pages/321)
  -Same.
- [Blank new blog generated with Jekyll-3.2.1 on Windows · Issue #5192 · jekyll/jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5192)
  It seemed relevant at first sight, but it is about **Gem based themes**, not remote themes.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

aaaah I was just bashing my head against this as well. I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve --verbose` and saw that `jekyll-remote-theme` was never being initialized at all (each plugin logs a `Requiring: jekyll-<thing>` line). Then I noticed this block in the Gemfile:

```
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
end
```

I added `"gem jekyll-remote-theme"` to that plugin block and that fixed it – doh!

There are a few notes in the jekyll changelogs about this Gemfile group, but I didn't find any of it super helpful in explaining what's going on here.

hope that helps!

Comment: ah there is this [comment on an issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6358#issuecomment-339859914) that sort of explains it

Comment: moved `gem "jekyll-remote-theme"` from outside of `group do` to inside of it in `Gemfile`, added `repository: Dixhom/dixhom.github.io` in `_config.yml` and it fixed the issue (http://dixhom.github.io/).